# Slurm Partition limits per account

Tags: slurm

I'm testing some slurm configurations. I've been able to set up partition login with the job_submit.lua plugin:

```
[root@controller ~]# sinfo
PARTITION AVAIL  TIMELIMIT  NODES  STATE NODELIST
tiny*        up 5-00:00:00      3   idle cn[1-40]    # 1 core
medium       up 5-00:00:00      3   idle cn[1-40]    # up to 4 core
large        up 5-00:00:00      3   idle cn[1-40]    # up to 20 core
```

I'd like to set limits on the number of running jobs in a partition for each  particular user. So for example, each user can run a max of each partition level jobs:

```
 200 running tiny jobs
 50 medium jobs
 10 large jobs
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please [do not edit your original question to include an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216722/271445). Instead, post an answer on your question.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, and thought it might be useful for others in case they search for something similar:

```
sacctmgr -i modify user where name=vagrant partition=tiny set maxjobs=200
sacctmgr -i modify user where name=vagrant partition=medium set maxjobs=50
sacctmgr -i modify user where name=vagrant partition=large set maxjobs=10
```